# Comparing two simplicial resolution in a model category

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, ct.category-theory, homotopy-theory, simplicial-stuff, model-categories

Suppose that is a nice model category $\mathbf{M}$ (cofibrantly generated,...). 
Suppose we have a two diagrams 
$$F,G: \Delta^{op}\rightarrow \mathbf{M} $$ 
and a natural transformation $\nu: F\rightarrow G $ such that for any natural number $n$,  $\nu_{n}: F(n)\rightarrow G(n) $ is a trivial cofibration. Is the induced map

$colim_{\Delta^{op}} F\rightarrow colim_{\Delta^{op}} G$ is a weak equivalence ?

Comment: This would hold if the colimit functor were left Quillen for the _injective_ model structure on $M^{\Delta^{op}}$. But the colimit functor should only be expected to be left Quillen for the _projective_ model structure (or maybe the Reedy model structure?). So presumably the answer is _no_, but I don't have a counterexample at hand.

Comment: However, from the question title, it sounds like you're actually interested in something different -- it sounds like you'd really like to know that if $F,G$ are both projectively cofibrant and weakly equivalent, then their colimits are also weakly equivalent. This is true, by [Ken Brown's lemma](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/factorization+lemma): a left Quillen functor preserves weak equivalences between cofibrant objects.

Comment: @TimCampion, thank for your comments, in my case the diagrams are not supposed to be cofibrant (in this case it will be trivial as you noticed in your second comment)